# How to query data using the build in Django functions in postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, django-queryset, django-dev-server

I am wanting to query data using the build in Django functions on postgresql database. When the highlighted line of code runs, I get the following error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'SimpleLazyObject'. When I change the database settings to the default database, then the query runs with no problems. What is the solution? I want to use the build in Django functions (that is, Entry.objects.dosomething) on postgresql database. How can I do this?[image]

Comment: I'm  really confused by the statement "when I change the database settings to the default database, the query runs".   Can you show us what settting you are changing, and what values work/don't work?

Comment: This is the updated settings: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'XXXXX',
        'USER': 'XXXXX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXX',
        'HOST': 'XXXXX',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
} When I used the default it worked, but not with the new settings. I was able to fix this problem by using Entry.objects.filter(user=) instead of Entry.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=). Thanks for the help.